# Restaurant serving meat during the 9 Days

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, nine-days

Can a kosher restaurant serve meat during the 9 days?

Asked another way, can I go to a "kosher" restaurant that does serve meat during the 9 days, and simply not eat meat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kosher meat restaurants work out the Nine Days in various ways. First and foremost, ask the restaurant, the *mashgiach*, and the kosher-certifying agency how they're handling this. (If their attitude is entirely lackadaisical, I'd think twice about their general kashrut.)

There are restaurants that have a large Sephardic clientèle, for whom the "Nine Days" restrictions are limited to "the week preceding Tisha B'Av"; furthermore, according to many Sephardic opinions, when Tisha B'Av is observed on a Sunday there is no "week preceding Tisha B'Av."

There are restaurants that offer big discounts if you will come in and have a *siyum* party there, celebrating the completion of significant Jewish learning, in which case the celebrants can have meat.

I've heard that some restaurants would basically hire someone to come in on a regular basis and make a *siyum*, and suddenly everyone in the restaurant is a "celebrant"; that's maybe a drop iffier.

Anyhow -- it's a custom to not eat meat during the Nine Days. It doesn't render your pots non-kosher! So assuming your kosher restaurant is paying proper attention to halachic detail, you should be able to eat non-meat items there. (Now please ask carefully when ordering, e.g. are the egg rolls or French fries fried in "meaty" oil.)

Comment: +1 in Mishna the minhag was if I am not wrong, the day itself before 9 beav

Comment: The meaty oil wouldnt be a problem. Only meat itself is forbidden or a meat mixture like a stew (even if you only eat the beans from cholent it would still be a problem). However, if there is no actual pieces of meat in the egg roll, there is no problem, even if the oil has fried meat in it.

Comment: @kouty the shulchan aruch says the week of. The RM"A says from Rosh Chodesh

Comment: @Mennyg
וְלֹא יֹאכַל בָּשָׂר וְלֹא יִשְׁתֶּה יָיִן. הַנֵּי מִילֵי לְאַחַר חֲצִי הַיּוֹם, וּבַסְּעֻדָּה הַמַּפְסֶקֶת שֶׁאֵין דַּעְתּוֹ לֶאֱכֹל אַחֲרֶיהָ סְעֻדַּת קְבַע. אֲבָל קֹדֶם חֲצִי הַיּוֹם אֲפִלּוּ בִּסְעֻדָּה הַמַּפְסֶקֶת, אוֹ בִסְעֻדָּה שֶׁאֵינָהּ מַפְסֶקֶת אֲפִלּוּ לְאַחַר חֲצִי הַיּוֹם, שָׁרֵי לֶאֱכֹל שְׁנֵי תַבְשִׁילִין, וּבְבָשָׂר וְיַיִן:

ברטנורא
Despite that SA stated the week. May be that it is not an Avera, may be also that not all kind of meat is prohibited for the period before 9 Beav.

Comment: Gemara:
תנא אבל אוכל הוא בשר מליח ושותה יין מגתו @Mennyg

Comment: While this doesn't often happen, there is another possibility, here. What if the kosher restaurant is owned by a non-Jew and he advertises that he's open serving meat only to non-Jews?

Comment: @Mennyg SA 552 prohibited basar maliach http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2912

Comment: @DanF, there actually is a non-Jewish-owned restaurant in Brookline. They are under the Sephardi hashgacha in the area (R' Aharon Hamaoui's Crown K) although their mashgichim are Ashkenazi.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Wow! This is really delving into a "combined" nuance. Sidebar - can a Gentile in a sense, violate the concept of "Lifnei Iver?" I.e. in the above case, eliminate the mashgichim. The place is kosher but owned by a Gentile.

Comment: @DanF, no clue. I would think that a non-Jew would be pattur from lifnei iver, because it isn't one of the 7 mitzvot livnei Noach. I mean, you really can't get away with a Chinese restaurant (even our American style) if it's not run by someone of east-Asian extraction (unless it's Schmulka Bernstein's ע”ה). Since meat isn't mamash treif during the 9 days, regardless, I don't think it's really a question of lifnei iver.

Comment: Re 3rd paragraph. You heard or read correctly. Last year, there was arestaurant in my neighborhood that specifically advertised this and they had set dinner times / shifts so you had to reserve a slot in advance. Also, a few yeshivot in my area make a fundraiser / BBQ/ siyum. Apparently, fleish during the 9 days attracts a lot of people as well as a lot of money for the yeshiva.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Shmulka ע”ה hired loads of Chinese workers. Have you seen Jews trying to fold up wontons and egg rolls? They come out looking more like meat / cabbage hamantaschen.

Comment: @Mennyg why should oil in which I fried chicken one minute ago be any different than eating the beans from a stew?

Answer (score 1):

There is a kosher restaurant near me that serves meat during part of the 9 days. They advertise that a few rabbanim from the neighborhood come in and make a siyum for customers. I believe that they take reservations for specific time slots so that they don't overcrowd the place.

AFAIK, this would work. However, some rabbanim have told me that they do not recommend the concept of making a siyum during the 9 days solely for the purpose of eating meat. I.e., it's fine if someone was learning and planning a siyum anyway and it occurs during the 9 days, but not to say, "I want to eat meat. Therefore, I'll learn a masechta so that I can make a siyum."